# Load Angular scripts on demand

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that must register Angular new Controllers obtained from a script. It should be able to charge the minimum amount of script to start the application and then obtain the necessary scripts on demand from other modules.

For instance:

- The application is loaded.
- A menu is displayed.
- After clicked on an item, it verifies that the module is not loaded, then the scripts are obtained through an http request.
- By getting the scripts must register all Controllers / Services to all urls of the new module will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AngularJs manual bootstrap.

Below is an example from AngularJs document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   Hello {{greetMe}}!
</div>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greetMe = 'World';
  }]);

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```